# OffsetDateTime field java8 : Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I am passing Datetime(`type='datetime-local'`) field from UI to backend. The format I'm sending is `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss`.
In the backend I am using OffsetDateTime to hold this value

```
class Test {
...
@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@ApiModelProperty(required = false, hidden = true)
OffsetDateTime expiryDate;
}
```

And then I am trying to store this in mysql DB of field type 'DATETIME'.

```
Timestamp expiryDate = offsetDateTimeToTimestamp(tag.getExpiryDate());
parameterMap.addValue("expiryDate", expiryDate);
namedJdbcTemplate.update(ADD_QUERY, parameterMap, keyHolder);
```

While doing this I am getting error as:

```
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2018-09-20T03:02:55 of type java.time.format.Parsed

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Failed to deserialize java.time.OffsetDateTime: (java.time.DateTimeException) Unable to obtain OffsetDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 2018-09-20T03:02:55 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Can somebody please help me with this assignment?

Comment: Can you please provide complete source code? Especially what inside `offsetDateTimeToTimestamp`. Thanks